# Aws lambda unzipped size error - aws chalice

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-lambda-layers, chalice

I am getting the following error from aws chalice, when i try to deploy the lambda function

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the 
UpdateFunctionCode operation: Unzipped size must be smaller than 93963569 
bytes
```

I know that the unzipped limit is 250 mb, but the error from chalice says the package has to be lesser that size ~90 mb. Why do i get this error with incorrect limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your size limits are probably due to import library sizes. You can offload your libraries into lambda layers. You can do this in Chalice through the chalice.config file. Either you can do automatic layers or calling layers you have created. Here is a walk through how to do each:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-aws-lambda-layers-with-aws-chalice/